# Allocating array of structs dynamically with malloc

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, dereference

I am trying to create dynamically an array of structs . Although with small sizes seems to work fine but the program crushes later(segmentation fault ) . When in have a big ipt_size it crushes very fast with nosense numbers so i assume the problem is in the way i allocate my array.

```
int create_ipt(int ipt_size,frame **ipt){
    int i;
    *ipt=malloc(ipt_size*sizeof(frame*));
 for(i=0;i<ipt_size;i++){
    ipt[i]=malloc(sizeof(frame));
     if (ipt[i]==NULL) return 1; //error
    ipt[i]->empty=1;
   }
 return 0; //success
}//create page table
```

I call the function with

```
     frame *ipt;
    create_ipt(ipt_size,&ipt);
```

Do you know what's happening ? frame has 3 ints inside

Comment: `*ipt=malloc(ipt_size*sizeof(frame*));` --> `*ipt=malloc(ipt_size*sizeof(frame));`.. `if (*ipt==NULL) return 1; for(i=0;i<ipt_size;i++){
    (*ipt)[i].empty=1;
   }`

Comment: Thank you man . That was the way . add your comment as an answer to make it green :)

Answer (score 2):

Look at the type of `*ipt`, it is `frame *`, that means, it's a pointer to type `frame`, i.e., points to a type `frame`. So you need to allocate memory which is capable of holding type `frame` and allocate the address to `*ipt`.

Change the memory allocation to reflect the same. Change

```
 *ipt=malloc(ipt_size*sizeof(frame*));
```

to

```
*ipt=malloc(ipt_size*sizeof(frame));
```

Then, have a look and revise (remove) the following statement `ipt[i]=malloc(sizeof(frame));`, you have already allocated memory for holding `ipt_size` number of elements.

After that, look at the dereference statement. Instead of

```
ipt[i]->empty=1;
```

you need to write

```
(*ipt)[i].empty = 1;
```

and that explicit parenthesis is there because of (to avoid the *unwanted* effect of) [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

Answer (score 0):

In `create_ipt`, you use:

`ipt` to access **ipt (pointer to the pointer you created in the main)

`*ipt` to access *ipt (pointer to the struct frame)

`**ipt` to access ipt (struct frame itself)

```
int create_ipt(int ipt_size, frame **ipt)
{
        int i;
        *ipt = malloc(ipt_size*sizeof(frame*)); // *ipt is the pointer to the struct frame you want to allocate memory)
        for(i=0; i < ipt_size; i++)
        {
                // If you only have integers you don't need to allocate memory to the struct, it's already allocated, but if you have char* you should malloc that var
                (*ipt)[i].text = malloc(text_size*sizeof(char));
                (*ipt)[i].empty = 1;
        }
        return 0;
}
```